# systemtap: registration error (rc -84)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, profiling, linux-device-driver, systemtap

I have a systemtap script that finds the latency of some functions inside a kernel module. 
(discussed here: [SystemTap script to profile latency of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463066/systemtap-script-to-profile-latency-of-functions))

It's working fine with a an older build version of my kernel module, but when I rebuilt the module from scratch and tried profiling it with the same script, for one or two functions I get `registration error (rc -84)`. It still works for majority of functions.

Any ideas what might cause this problem? I tried adding -DSTP_NO_OVERLOAD but it didn't help.

Comment: rc -84 is explained, e.g., here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22436660/3440745.